# Numpy: Get minimum value indices in array, ignoring specific elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have symmetric matrix of distances:

```
dist = np.array([[0., 3., 6., 1.],
                 [3., 0., 5., 2.],
                 [6., 5., 0., 2.],
                 [1., 2., 5., 0.]])
```

So I need to extract indices of minimal values in it in loop, ignoring diagonal elements and elements returned in a previous iterations ((i,j) and (j,i) because of matrix symmetricity).

How can I do it?
The part about ignoring diagonal I do with

```
np.fill_diagonal(distance_matrix, np.inf)
a = np.unravel_index(distance_matrix.argmin(), distance_matrix.shape)
```

but what about ignoring already returned elements? Otherwise I can only get an [0,3].

Comment: Are you looking for all minimal values?  so as for your example above if we had another `1` in the lower triangle would you want both values returned?

Comment: @Chinny84, this is equivalent combinations for me due to this is distances between i and j. But actually it's not important for me if there are some equal min values, I need only one each iteration in loop. If equal, I want to see it in the next iteration

Comment: Set previously returned elements to `np.inf`, too.

Comment: @DYZ It works, but what if I am not to change not diagonal elements?

Comment: @lizaveta Why not? You can make a copy of the original array and modify it, if you want to preserve the original array. Or you can create a mask - an array of the same size that has 1's and `inf`s - and multiply the mask by the original matrix before calculating the minimal elements.

Comment: Are you looking for the index closest to (smallest distance from) each index? I.e., for your array above, are you looking for a way to find the vector `[3, 3, 3, 0]`, since the last column/row is the closest to indexes 0–2, and the first column/row is closest to the last index? I’m trying to make sure I understand what you’re really looking for.